# i have a geojson layer button and when i click i have to zoom to the particular layer

Tags: zooming, openlayers

this is my layer and i have assigned it to a button, but the zoom is not working when I click the layer button.  i tried adding the zoom inside the layer but its not working.

```js
rainfall1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    //title: 'CA_DEVELOPMENT_PLAN',
    // extent: [-180, -90, -180, 90],
     visible:false,
     source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url:"./data/village.geojson",
         zoom: 12,
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()        
      }),
       
     style:function(feature) {
       labelStyle.getText().setText(feature.getProperties().CA_NAME);              
                 
       return style1;
     },
     declutter: true,
  });

document.getElementById("lyr").onclick = function() { 
  layer1.setVisible(!rainfall1.getVisible());
};

var bindLayerButtonToggle = function (lyr, layer) {
  document.getElementById(lyr).onclick = function() { 
      layer.setVisible(!layer.getVisible());
  };
}

bindLayerButtonToggle("lyr", rainfall1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setVisible` will not zoom to a layer, it just turns it on or off.

Instead, you would have to update the view extent, and match it with the layer extent

```js
map.getView().fit(rainfall1.getSource().getExtent());
```

Comment: hey i tried that but now the geojson is not visible

Comment: and the setVisible is for toggle on and off that button for that geojson layer, so when i clicked the button the layer have to zoom in and then when i off it it has to be back to normal

Answer (score 0):

@JGH's answer might work in some cases but if this is the first time the layer is made visible the source will not be loaded, so if there are no features you will need to wait for it to load before zooming.

```
if (rainfall1.getSource().getFeatures().length > 0) {
  map.getView().fit(rainfall1.getSource().getExtent());
} else {
  rainfall1.getSource().once('featuresloadend', function() [
    map.getView().fit(rainfall1.getSource().getExtent());
  });
```

}